MarkLogic Timestamps and Search
I have three records in a collection with time information recorded like this:
{utcTime: "13:28:00+0000", utc: 1329398880000, etDate: "02/16", etTime: "08:28:00-0500"}
{utcTime: "13:02:00+0000", utc: 1333976569000, etDate: "04/09", etTime: "09:02:00-0400"}
{utcTime: "13:14:00+0000", utc: 1398172449000, etDate: "04/22", etTime: "09:14:00-0400"}

When I do a search for all etTime columns between 09:00:00-0400 and 09:30:00-0400, all three records are returned because MarkLogic is converting -0400 to UTC and doing a comparison. 09:00:00-0400 is equal to 13:00:00+0000 so all the records are returned, as expected.
But how can I avoid this timezone comparison?  If a user wants only records between 09:00:00 and 09:30:00, regardless of the time shift, the 09:02:00 and 09:14:00 records should be the only records returned and 08:28:00-0500 is ignored?
Is there a way to do this?

You could put a String range index on the etTime property and search for things that start with "09:"
cts:search(doc(), 
  cts:and-query((
    cts:json-property-range-query("etTime", ">", "09:*"),
    cts:json-property-range-query("etTime", "<", "10:*")
  ))
)


likewise, a TDE template taking the hour part and removing the ":"  and ending up with an integer:  1328, 1302, 1314 etc.  Then query via optic or via cts:column-range-query() all as numbers.  Only catch is to zero-pad the minute part - but that is already done based on the sample

Similarly, you could also lop off the timezone from the string value, then index as a dateTime column that was constructed from the dateTime string without timezones
